# Spring Declarative Transaction is not working (transaction not committed)

Tags: java, spring, transactions

Spring Declarative Transaction is not working (not committed).

## Spring Configuration

```
  <!-- DATASOURCE -->

   <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
      <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driver}"/>
      <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
      <property name="username" value="${jdbc.user}"/>
      <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
      <property name="initialSize" value="${dbcp.initialSize}"/>
      <property name="maxActive" value="${dbcp.maxActive}"/>
      <property name="maxIdle" value="${dbcp.maxIdle}"/>
      <property name="maxWait" value="${dbcp.maxWait}"/>
      <property name="poolPreparedStatements" value="${dbcp.poolPreparedStatements}"/>
      <property name="validationQuery" value="select 1 from dual"/>
      <property name="testOnBorrow" value="${dbcp.testOnBorrow}"/>
      <property name="maxOpenPreparedStatements" value="${dbcp.maxOpenPreparedStatements}"/>
      <property name="logAbandoned" value="${dbcp.logAbandoned}"/>
      <property name="removeAbandoned" value="${dbcp.removeAbandoned}"/>
      <property name="removeAbandonedTimeout" value="${dbcp.removeAbandonedTimeout}"/>
      **<property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="false"/>**
   </bean>

  <!-- IBATIS -->

    <bean id="sqlMapClient" class="org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientFactoryBean">
        <property name="configLocations" value="classpath:/config/ibatis/sqlMapConfig.xml"/>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sqlMapClientTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientTemplate">
      <property name="sqlMapClient" ref="sqlMapClient"/>
    </bean>

  <!-- TRANSACTION -->

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>

   <tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
      <tx:attributes>
            <tx:method name="*" propagation="REQUIRED" isolation="READ_COMMITTED" timeout="10" read-only="false"/>
      </tx:attributes>
   </tx:advice>

    <aop:config>
        <aop:pointcut id="serviceMethods" expression="execution(public * com.store.web.front.service.*.*(..))"/>
        <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="serviceMethods"/>
    </aop:config>
```

## Controller Bean

```
package com.store.web.front.controller;

    public interface TestTxControllerIF {
       public ModelAndView transaction();
    }

package com.store.web.front.controller;

    @Controller
    public class TestTxControllerImpl implements TestTxControllerIF {

        @Autowired
        protected TestTxServiceIF testService;

        Logger                    logger = Logger.getLogger(TestTxControllerIF.class);

        @Override
        @RequestMapping(value = "/test/tx.html")
        public ModelAndView transaction() {

            logger.info("# TestTxController.transaction() - " + testService);

            testService.transaction();
            return new ModelAndView("main");
        }
}
```

## Service Bean

```
    package com.store.web.front.service;

        public interface TestTxServiceIF {
            public void transaction();
        }

    package com.store.web.front.service;

        @Service
        public class TestTxServiceImpl implements TestTxServiceIF {

            Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(TestTxServiceImpl.class);

            @Autowired
            protected TestDaoIF testDao;

            @Override
            public void transaction() {

                logger.info("# TestTxService.transaction()");

                Test test1 = new Test("111", "First");
                Test test2 = new Test("222", "Second");
                Test test3 = new Test("333", "Third");

                testDao.insertTest(test1);        
                logger.info("# Successfully inserted!!! - " + test1);

                testDao.insertTest(test2);        
                testDao.insertTest(test3);
            }
        }
```

## DAO Bean

```
package com.store.web.front.dao;

    public interface TestDaoIF {
        public void insertTest(Test test);
    }

package com.store.web.front.dao;

    @Repository
    public class TestDaoImpl extends AbstractIBatisDao implements TestDaoIF {    

        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(TestTxServiceImpl.class);

        @Override
        public void insertTest(Test test) {

            logger.info("# TestDao.insertTest()");

            template.insert("test.insertTest", test);
        }
    }
```

## Result & Question

After deploying and sending request "/test/tx.html", the transaction executes without a problem, but database records are not persisted.
I suppose, Transaction is not committed.
What could the problem be?

## Log

```
DEBUG> 11:02:10 - DispatcherServlet with name 'spring-dispatcher' processing request for [/test/tx.html] ☜ DispatcherServlet.java:781
DEBUG> 11:02:10 - Invoking request handler method: public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.store.web.front.controller.TestTxControllerImpl.transaction() ☜ HandlerMethodInvoker.java:134
INFO > 11:02:10 - # TestTxController.transaction() - com.store.web.front.service.TestTxServiceImpl@126cb1a ☜ TestTxControllerImpl.java:23
INFO > 11:02:10 - # TestTxService.transaction() ☜ TestTxServiceImpl.java:25
INFO > 11:02:10 - # TestDao.insertTest() ☜ TestDaoImpl.java:20
DEBUG> 11:02:10 - Opened SqlMapSession [com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapSessionImpl@1bc345a] for iBATIS operation ☜ SqlMapClientTemplate.java:177
DEBUG> 11:02:10 - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource ☜ DataSourceUtils.java:112
DEBUG> 11:02:10 - Obtained JDBC Connection [jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE, UserName=STORE, Oracle JDBC driver] for iBATIS operation ☜ SqlMapClientTemplate.java:194
DEBUG> 11:02:10 - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource ☜ DataSourceUtils.java:312
INFO > 11:02:10 - # Successfully inserted!!! - Test [id=111, name=First] ☜ TestTxServiceImpl.java:33
```

Comment: What's the fully qualified name of the TestTxServiceImpl class?

Comment: Use STS, and check if the markers for the advices are shown next to your Service methods. If the do not show up, then maybe you advice is not correct configured.

Comment: Fully qualified class name is "com.store.web.front.service.TestTxServiceImpl".

Comment: Can you let me know how to check using STS?

Comment: Hi Ralph! Can you explain to me more exactly.
For example, What menu and how to use...

Comment: Don't know if you've gotten to a solution yet, but you may find annotation-based transactions easier to debug.

Comment: can you try using <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />  as well

Answer (score 0):

I found this problems's reason.
When transaction declaration file was loaded by DispatcherServlet,
transaction control was successful.
But the file was load by ContextLoaderListener, transaction control was not good.
I don't know why this difference is occurred.
Can you explain to me?

Answer (score 0):

Beans are decorated with "AOP stuff" by `BeanPostProcessor`s (in your case probably by `AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator`). These post-processor beans are **context instance specific**.

If you configure AOP in your **servlet context** and you have your target beans in the **root context** (or vice versa), then that is why the pointcut is not applied.

Common practice is to have lower level beans (services and DAOs) together with AOP config in the **root context** and leave only UI beans (MVC stuff) in **servlet context** .